# How to command line build a .app binary for OSX out of a Qt app?

Tags: macos, qt, otool, install-name-tool, macdeployqt

I am preparing a shell script to build my QtApp into a .app for OSX. I do the following in my script

```
qmake MyApp.pro -spec macx-clang CONFIG+=release CONFIG+=x86_64 CONFIG+=qml_debug
make
macdeployqt MyApp/MyApp.app
```

And I get the MyApp.app. Great until here! But when I double click open it, I get the following error:

`You can’t open the application “MyApp.app” because it is not supported on this type of Mac.`

I tried to search around this problem. Looks like I need to add some more lines of code in my script related to `otool` & `install_name_tool` as mentioned in the following official link from Qt:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/osx-deployment.html#macdeploy

Its fair explanation of which tools & what works below Qt to get the final .app, but I am not able to figure out what exactly to put in my script so that I get a MyApp.app statically linked with Qt libraries which runs on my osx machine after the build.

**The Question:

Can someone please point out what to add in my script after the macdeployqt command to get a proper MyApp.app for OSX ?**

Btw, running `otool` command on MyApp gives the following output:

```
otool -L MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp
MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp:
@rpath/QtQuick.framework/Versions/5/QtQuick (compatibility version 5.6.0, current version 5.6.1)
@rpath/QtQml.framework/Versions/5/QtQml (compatibility version 5.6.0, current version 5.6.1)
@rpath/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/5/QtNetwork (compatibility version 5.6.0, current version 5.6.1)
@rpath/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore (compatibility version 5.6.0, current version 5.6.1)
/System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 275.0.0)
@rpath/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui (compatibility version 5.6.0, current version 5.6.1)
/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Versions/A/AGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.1.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1226.10.1)
```

Comment: Do you have a static Qt build to begin with?

Comment: @KubaOber I have installed Qt 5.7 with android, ios & osx. I am able to build all the version from my QtCreator. I am also able to make my script build for android & ios binaries but only stuck with this osx part. Does that mean I have static Qt build ?

Comment: @KubaOber I am new into Qt. I want to build static Qt libraries into MyApp.app but i dont know how to do it ? Can you please tell me how to statically link to to Qt libraries if it would solve my problem here ?

Comment: The Qt binaries you've downloaded are not static libraries. You have to build Qt yourself as a static library. Once you do, any application you build with it will be statically linked - you don't have to do anything special for that to happen then. You should start by building your own copy of Qt.

Comment: @KubaOber Do you mean that I have to download the complete Qt source & build it as a static library from source ? The Qt I installed from qt.io has created the folder named Qt in my home directory. Isn't there any configuration I can with in the existing Qt installation to enforce static linking ?

Comment: "I have to download the complete Qt source & build it as a static library from source" Yes. "Isn't there any configuration I can with in the existing Qt installation to enforce static linking" No. A Qt installation can either be dynamic or static, it can't be both. Qt's binary installers don't offer the option of downloading a statically configured Qt, that's all.

Comment: If you're using Qt in a professional/serious-amateur setting, you're expected to build it yourself anyway - that should be perhaps one of the first steps you undertake.

Comment: To speed up debug builds, you should in fact have two Qt builds: one configured for dynamic linking, used to debug your code, and another compiled for static linking, used for releases. Qt builds are meant to coexist, you can have dozens of different Qt versions and configurations all existing side-by-side. Just let Qt Creator know about them. From command line you select the Qt build by running that build's `qmake` on your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info until yet.   If I wish to go with dynamic linking, `macdeployqt MyApp/MyApp.app` looks to be copying the required frameworks into the `Frameworks` folder of the bundle. What else should I do in my script to get the final .app bundle ?